# PHP - Adding a new element inside element XML

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to add multiple elements, within a parent element with PHP (XML):

This is what I am trying to achieve:

```
<ns0:XmlInterchange xmlns:ns0="http://www.edi.com.au/EnterpriseService/" xmlns:ext="http://esb.dsv.com/ExtensionFunctions">
  <ns0:InterchangeInfo>
     <ns0:Date>2017-07-20 13:41:48</ns0:Date>
     <ns0:XmlType>Verbose</ns0:XmlType>
     <ns0:Source>
        <ns0:EnterpriseCode>Company</ns0:Enterprisecode>
     </ns0:Source>
 </ns0:InterchangeInfo>
</ns0:XmlInterchange>
```

I have below PHP code:

```
$xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$xml->formatOutput = true;

$interchange = $xml->createElementNS('ns0', 'ns0:XmlInterchange');
$interchange->setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/', 'xmlns:ns0', 'http://www.edi.com.au/EnterpriseService/');
$interchange->setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/', 'xmlns:ext', 'http://esb.dsv.com/ExtensionFunctions');
$xml->appendChild($interchange); //Add above attributes to our element. <!Xmlinterchange->

$item = $xml->createElement('ns0:InterchangeInfo');
$item->appendChild($xml->createElement('ns0:Date',$invoice_date));
$item->appendChild($xml->createElement('ns0:XmlType','Verbose'));
$item = $xml->createElement('ns0:Source');
$item->appendChild($xml->createElement('ns0:EnterpriseCode','Company'));
$interchange->appendChild($item);
unset($item); //Reset $item, so we can use the variable again.
```

However, above outputs:

```
<ns0:XmlInterchange xmlns:ns0="http://www.edi.com.au/EnterpriseService/" xmlns:ext="http://esb.dsv.com/ExtensionFunctions">
  <ns0:Source>
    <ns0:EnterpriseCode>Company</ns0:EnterpriseCode>
  </ns0:Source>
</ns0:XmlInterchange>
```

I want to be able to get the `<ns0:Source>` element to be within the `<ns0:InterChangeInfo>` element, but together with the other elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to append the `<ns0:Source>` to the `<ns0:InterchangeInfo>`. After that append the `<ns0:InterchangeInfo>` to `<ns0:XmlInterchange>`.

Remember: `->appendChild()` means not append to but append inside. So `$a->appendChild($b);` means you append b inside a.

Try:

```
$xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$xml->formatOutput = true;

$interchange = $xml->createElementNS('ns0', 'ns0:XmlInterchange');
$interchange->setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/', 'xmlns:ns0', 'http://www.edi.com.au/EnterpriseService/');
$interchange->setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/', 'xmlns:ext', 'http://esb.dsv.com/ExtensionFunctions');

$item = $xml->createElement('ns0:InterchangeInfo');
$item->appendChild($xml->createElement('ns0:Date',$invoice_date));
$item->appendChild($xml->createElement('ns0:XmlType','Verbose'));

$source = $xml->createElement('ns0:Source');
$source->appendChild($xml->createElement('ns0:EnterpriseCode','Company'));
$item->appendChild($source);

$interchange->appendChild($item);

$xml->appendChild($interchange);
```

Comment: How should I append it? can you provide an example? Should I still use the $item variable?

Comment: Updated my post. Hope that it is right. Append an object only then when all childs are set correctly.

Comment: Above outputs the same as what I got. It deletes the `<ns0:InterchangeInfo>` and replaces it with `<ns0:Source>`

Comment: You overwrite your `$item` there. I used a new variable name. Try this.